# How to source R file and run it at the same time in R script

Tags: r

I am trying to make source and run r script in another r script at the same time

```
library(randomForest) 
path.name = "D:/Courses/Bioinformatics Diploma/Statistical Analysis and Visualization/Assignments/Assignment 1/Assignment_01_Data.csv"
GE_Data_Modification.R = read.table(path.name, sep = ',', header = T, row.names = 1)
GE_Data_Modification.R = as.data.frame(t(GE_Data_Modification.R)) 
GE_Data_Modification.R = na.roughfix(GE_Data_Modification.R) 
GE_Data_Modification.R = as.data.frame(t(GE_Data_Modification.R))
source("E:/Stat/Lectures/GE_Data_Modification.R")
GE_Mean = apply(GE_Data_Modification.R, 2, mean) 
GE_SD = apply(GE_Data_Modification.R, 2, sd) 
GE_Data_Normalization.R = t(t(GE_Data_Modification.R[,1:ncol(GE_Data_Modification.R)])-GE_Mean) 
GE_Data_Normalization.R = t(t(GE_Data_Modification.R[,1:ncol(GE_Data_Modification.R)])/GE_SD)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use rstudio jobs to avoid locking the console

```
library(randomForest) 
path.name = "D:/Courses/Bioinformatics Diploma/Statistical Analysis and Visualization/Assignments/Assignment 1/Assignment_01_Data.csv"
GE_Data_Modification.R = read.table(path.name, sep = ',', header = T, row.names = 1)
GE_Data_Modification.R = as.data.frame(t(GE_Data_Modification.R)) 
GE_Data_Modification.R = na.roughfix(GE_Data_Modification.R) 
GE_Data_Modification.R = as.data.frame(t(GE_Data_Modification.R))
rstudioapi::jobRunScript("E:/Stat/Lectures/GE_Data_Modification.R")
GE_Mean = apply(GE_Data_Modification.R, 2, mean) 
GE_SD = apply(GE_Data_Modification.R, 2, sd) 
GE_Data_Normalization.R = t(t(GE_Data_Modification.R[,1:ncol(GE_Data_Modification.R)])-GE_Mean) 
GE_Data_Normalization.R = t(t(GE_Data_Modification.R[,1:ncol(GE_Data_Modification.R)])/GE_SD)
```